# Is the tower game shown in the 'Hero Wars' ad a real game?

Tags: game-identification

I was playing a game on my phone, and an [advertisement](https://fb.watch/3Sb-ooOiEY/) appears about the game *Hero Wars*, but *Hero Wars* does not play anything like what is shown in the ad.

The advertisement shows a hero being placed on various levels of a tower to defeat enemies and level up:

[image: animated GIf of the ad]]

[image: Hero in tower] [image: Hero defeating enemy]

[image: New Tower with bigger enemies]

Does the gameplay shown in the advertisement exist as an actual game?

[Here's the full ad on Facebook.](https://www.facebook.com/herowarsalliance/videos/3547563985326593/)

Comment: there's also now a version of all of the fake mobile ad games available as a PC standalone: [YEAH! YOU WANT "THOSE GAMES," RIGHT? SO HERE YOU GO! NOW, LET'S SEE YOU CLEAR THEM!](https://store.steampowered.com/app/2348100/YEAH_YOU_WANT_THOSE_GAMES_RIGHT_SO_HERE_YOU_GO_NOW_LETS_SEE_YOU_CLEAR_THEM/)

Answer (score 28):

Really, there's a general rule to go by: when you see a mobile game ad, there are very good chances what is shown is not gameplay, or not even related to the game. Some of these mobile games (Homescapes) are even [being sued for misleading advertising](https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-54509970).

So yeah, except for the characters in the ad, nothing of what is shown exists in the 'Hero Wars' game.

> Does the gameplay shown in the advertisement exist as an actual game?

I would expect no. The gameplay shown is a very easy puzzle, and they are banking on the dumb (but I guess working) trend in mobile advertising where the puzzle is basic, kindergarten math (usually shared with some sort of challenge like *"98% OF THE POPULATION CAN'T DO THIS, CAN YOU?"*) Like the puzzle shown in this ad. Just pick your character, and then go and check every enemy. Is his level HIGHER? OR LOWER? If lower put against.

You might find a puzzle that looks like this in a puzzle compilation game, but a game that has this basic mechanic as it's only feature? Not that I know of.

EDIT: There is now also a GameTheory episode that digs down as to why those ads never seem to fit with what the game actually is.

EDIT: Years later, it seems someone DID make a game all about those mobile game ads if you wanna play them.

https://store.steampowered.com/app/2348100/YEAH_YOU_WANT_THOSE_GAMES_RIGHT_SO_HERE_YOU_GO_NOW_LETS_SEE_YOU_CLEAR_THEM/

Answer (score 17):

Aside from being a misleading advertisement used by "Hero Wars" and "Mighty Party"
this was actually turned into a game and released on April 02, 2021 by the developer [TuTapp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=TuTapp).

It is currently available on the Google Play store under the name [Hero Castle Wars](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tutapp.herocastlewars) but  recommending the app is difficult because it not only constantly prompts the user to rate it but the levels sometimes cannot even be solved as seen in the following screenshots.

[image: Hero Castle Wars gameplay]

> Does the gameplay shown in the advertisement exist as an actual game?

Yes, not in the games that use the ad, but it exists.

Comment: I guess somebody figured that if they make ads of this maybe someone wants to play that.

Yeah it seems rapidly made, but if you want to play that there is a solution now!

Comment: I think that there actually was a different way to solve level 3 that would work. For example, if you have an extra skill that will deal some additional damage before you fight the boss. But I soon uninstalled it, because although the levels technically are winnable, they soon become extremely luck-based, with constant restarting.

Comment: By the way, another developer has more recently created a second version, "Hero Tower Wars". Prettier graphics and slightly less obnoxious ads, but the difficulty has possibly gone too far in the other direction, so easy it's a bit boring.

Comment: @ThrawnCA in the screens there seems to be some button on the top left that could do something similar to what you suggested. And if I know this sort of games, those are "power ups" that you can buy with some sort of in game currency... that you can buy with real world money....

Answer (score 9):

This advertisement is misleading and does not show actual gameplay.
Here is a video showing the differences.

Mobile game advertisements are often misleading, but this is an actual game, even if the shown gameplay is fake.

Comment: Have you watched this video...? At 3:45 she discovers that the gameplay in the ad is real, but only a very small part of the game.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft That's probably literally only there in order to avoid the misleading ad legal action -- they show that the ad does show something that _is_ in the game.